# ¿Como comparo strings en python en busqueda de palabras en común?

Tags: python, string

necesito una ayuda con este código. El programa debería recibir tres cadenas, luego comparar las cadenas entre si y devolver las palabras en común entre las cadenas de texto. Soy nuevo en python, no me judgen.

```
# This program request 3 arrays and then found the letters or 
# words that the 3 arrays have in common in the beginning.

array_a = input('Array_1')
array_b = input('Array_2')
array_c = input('Array_3')
array_a = array_a.lstrip()
array_b = array_b.lstrip()
array_c = array_c.lstrip()
a = 0

lista = [len(array_a), len(array_b), len(array_c)]
lista.sort()

for i in range(lista[0]):
    if array_a[i] == array_b[i] == array_c[i]:
        a += 1

print()
print('The most common prefix is', array_a[0:a])
```

Comment: ¿Y la tercera cadena para que sería?

Comment: Fue un error al escribirlo, debe comparar todas las cadenas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supersimple: usa `intersection()` de sets.

La interseccion de conjuntos A y B genera un nuevo conjunto (`set`) con los elementos comunes:

```
array_a = "en una aldea lejana vivía un pequeño hobbit"
array_b = "el hobbit también un hermano en una aldea lejana"
array_c = "donde vivia con un abuelo"

palabras = set(array_a.split()).intersection(set(array_b.split())).intersection(set(array_c.split()))
print(palabras)
```

`array_a.split()` divide la frase en palabras, con las que formaras un `set()`. Luego sólo queda aplicar sucesivamente la intersection.

produce:

```
{'un'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras lo que hace es obtener el prefijo en común entre las 3 cadenas tal y como cuenta la propia descripción del código en ingles. Si por ejemplo introduces las cadenas "ABCD", "ABCX", y "ABXX" el código te imprimirá el prefijo en común que es "AB".

Si lo que buscas es un código que te imprima las palabras en común de 3 strings entonces tu código podría ser algo así:

```
import functools

strings = [input('String_%d: '%(i+1)) for i in range(3)]
palabras = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a&b, (set(s.split(" ")) for s in strings))

print("palabras en comun:", *palabras)
```

Comment: Overkill. Basta con una simple llamada a `intersection()` para lograr lo deseado.

Comment: Si, bueno, a&b viene siendo lo mismo que hacer a.intersection(b) @CandidMoe Si es por simplificar aqui tienes todo el código en una sola línea `print("palabras en comun:", *functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a&b, (set(s.split(" ")) for s in [input('String_%d: '%(i+1)) for i in range(3)])))`